# Keeping macros when writing to .xlsm using Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, excel, linux, openpyxl

I have a fairly straightforward script. It is supposed to replace all the data in one sheet of an `.xlsm` workbook. The workbook contains macros which I would like to keep. Unfortunately, **I cannot find a way to do this on UBUNTU**, not Windows

I cannot use `xlwings` because it needs an instance of Excel which I cannot get on Ubuntu.

I have tried to use `openpyxl` with `keep_vba` but the macros are gone when it is done writing. How can I possibly keep my macros if I am running this script on Ubuntu?

This is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import xlrd
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

all_data=pd.read_csv('full.csv')
file_path = 'data.xlsm'
wb = load_workbook(filename=file_path, read_only = False, keep_vba = True)

sheet=wb['Sheet1']
sheet.delete_rows(sheet.min_row, sheet.max_row)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(dataframe_to_rows(all_data, index=False), sheet.min_row):
    print(f"{r_idx}...")
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, sheet.min_column):
        sheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save(file_path)
```

Also, the part of the script that is writing to the sheet is taking really long. I am referring to the `for` loop. If there is a more efficient way of doing it please let me know. Right now it is taking almost 3 hours to write 150k rows. The rows are very simple. The csv rows look like this and that is all that is going into the sheet.

```
Symbol,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
A,2024-Feb-16,133.59,136.27,133.59,134.84,1066800
AA,2024-Feb-16,27.34,28.03,27.16,27.4,4686200
AAA,2024-Feb-16,25.22,25.22,25.0999,25.124,7100
AAAU,2024-Feb-16,19.78,19.96,19.76,19.915,3564400
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why use Pandas at all? You can chain the CSV and the sheet together. Seeing as you delete all the cells in the worksheet, there's no need to look at `sheet.min_row` or `sheet.min_column`, the latter of which will be calculated for each row. Whether you're on Windows or Linux won't affect how macros are handled, so you might need to provide more information on what isn't working.

Comment: @CharlieClark so i think i get what you are saying. First delete the sheet `Consol` and create a new one, right? I have managed to delete the sheet and create a new one. But populating the sheet is taking very long, like 4 hours for 120k rows. I am using

`all_data=pd.read_csv('full.csv')`

`ws = wb.create_sheet(title='Consol')`

`for r in dataframe_to_rows(all_data, index=False, header=True):`
    
    `ws.append(r)`

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Questions like that are fairly useless. How long does it take to open and close the file without doing anything? Is the file subsequently usable by Excel. For performance numbers, please see the section in the documentation but 120k rows should be a matter of seconds. You must be doing something else that you're not showing.